# How do click and drag MKPointAnnotation on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mapkit, core-location, mkpointannotation

I'm using a MKMapView on OS X with a MKPointAnnotation based on my current coordinate. I'd like to be able to click and drag this pin annotation around, however clicking and dragging results in scrolling the mapview. I can't figure out any method that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... I didn't set my controller as the MKMapViewDelegate. Simply had to conform to all the annotation related methods.